# Grails 3 collections to one then sort

Tags: grails

I am not sure if this can be done,

I have 3 collections all with a current date tag. I am wanting to sort all the collections by date and give back only one collections.

my collections are Picture, Text and Video.
I can pull out each collection and sort by date on its own but i would like to merge them all and then sort by date. Is this possible. Currently I am using a separate domain that keep the order of the collections and pulls out each object one by one in order, but this seems a bad way of doing it.

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by collections, are you referring to domain objects?

Comment: build an inherit schema: Text, Video and Picture inherits from Item, and work at this level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I've understood you right, you can try to use [sort()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method.
def sortedCommon = (textCollection + videoCollection + pictureCollection).sort{it.date}

Or as Miguel Prz said: "build an inherit schema: Text, Video and Picture inherits from Item, and work at this level". It's a good suggestion.